# add object to array based on id in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have location data like an example(ex: [{country:"US", area:"virginia"},{country:"AUSTRALIA",area:"sydney"},{country:"INDIA",area:"bangalore"}] . i want to add each location to one array by clicking add button. In UI, i have fetched the location data and displayed those. While adding any particular location by clicking the adjacent add button then first location is getting added to that array. Each time it is adding the first location object to that array. How to add location based on particular button click(ex. if i click the button for "INDIA" location then "INDIA" location object only will add to the array.

i have created the actions and reducer for the adding operation. it is adding  but only the first item.

actioncreator.js

```
export const addLocation = id =>({
      type: ADD_LOCATION,
      id
  });
```

reducer.js

```
case 'ADD_LOCATION':
        let addedlocation = state.location.find(obj=>obj.id===action.id)
               return{
                   ...state,
                conLocations: [...state.conLocations,addedlocation]
               }
```

conLocations is the array where i have to add the location object.

add button UI part:

```
<div className="col-padding"><h3>Locations List</h3><hR/>
                             {this.props.location.map(loc=>(<div className="jd" key={loc.id}>
                             <span><strong>{loc.mruCode} - {loc.division} - {loc.country} | {loc.currency} | {loc.uom}</strong></span><br/><button className="call-to-action"onClick={(id)=>{this.handleClick(loc.id)}}>Add Location</button><hR/></div>))}
                            </div>
```

connect to componenet code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(id)=>{dispatch(addLocation(id))}
    }
}
```

i have a doubt in my reducer function. it is adding the first item based on its id but next time state is not updated. so it is adding the first item again . How to solve it

Comment: What does your `handleClick` function look like?

Comment: Where is id in your data? [{country:"US", area:"virginia"},{country:"AUSTRALIA",area:"sydney"},{country:"INDIA",area:"bangalore"}] did not contain id. Can you share full data ?

Comment: @LadiAden hi it is something like ->``` handleClick (id){
          return this.props.addLocation(id);
     }   ```

Comment: @bkm412 it looks like in network tab ...  0: {mruCode: "7300", country: "CA", countryText: "Canada", division: "WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL",…}
1: {mruCode: "1700", country: "US", countryText: "United States", division: "WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL",…}
2: {mruCode: "1000", country: "US", countryText: "United States", division: "WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL",…}

Comment: @user741158. But in your data, there is no key `id`. Please share screenshot `console.log(this.props.location)` at your UI code. If your id is undefined, `obj.id===action.id` means `undefined ===undefined` and always become true.

Comment: @bkm412 is it possible to use index to add locations object into array? because in console it's showing like above. no id . it will be very much helpful for me

Comment: I am not sure about your issue, but I will leave answer for reference purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your data

```
const location = [
{mruCode: "7300", country: "CA", countryText: "Canada", division: "WORLDWIDE_AGRICULTURAL",…},
{mruCode: "1700", country: "US", countryText: "United States", division: "WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL",…}
]
```

I think `mruCode` is primary key. If other key is primary key, just change to that.

#### At button

```
onClick={()=>{this.props.addLocation(loc.mruCode)}
```

#### mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode)}
    }
}
```

#### Action

```
export const addLocation = mruCode =>({
      type: ADD_LOCATION,
      payload : mruCode
  });
```

#### Reducer

```
case 'ADD_LOCATION':
        let addedlocation = state.location.find(obj=>obj.mruCode===action.payload)
               return{
                   ...state,
                conLocations: [...state.conLocations,addedlocation]
               }
```

## If you add all location

#### Action

```
export const addAllLocation = () => ({
    type : 'ADD_ALL_LOCATION' // If you use type variable, please replace this
})
```

#### Reducer

```
case 'ADD_ALL_LOCATION':
   return {
      ...state,
      conLocations: [...state.location]
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is awesome. truly amazing. i need one more help. i have to add all location by clicking 'add all location' button. How to define reducer and action for that? if possible give me some suggestions on that.

Comment: I added your request.

Comment: @bkm12 one more request if possible please help me. have to hide the 'Add Button'   after clicking. It is based on mruCode